# Работа с таблицами (массивами) в calabash-cucumber

Tags: android, ruby, test-automation, android-testing, cucumber

Изучаю автоматическое тестирование calabash-cucumber. Дошел до раздела с описанием Scenario Outline, Example и работы с таблицами. Но не могу реализовать такой вот пример:

`Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app
    Given my app is launch
    Then I enter text <text> into field with id <id> 
    Then I press the <button> button
    Examples:
        | text       | id             | button   |
        | email_1    | login_email    | Ok       |
        | password_1 | login_password | Ok       |`

Идея в том, в `< >` должно браться значение из таблицы. Понимаю, что тут, по идее, должна быть работа с массивами, но не могу найти внятного описание как это сделать, а с языком Ruby я, как бы, не очень знаком. Может кто подскажет tutorial какой-то, или пример с объяснением?

Попробовал упростить задачу:

`Scenario Outline: As a valid user I can log into my app 
Given I have table Text 
Then I enter text "text@mail" into field with id "login_email" 
Then I enter text <Text> into field with id <id> 
Then I press the "ok" button 
Examples: 
| Text | id | | Password | login_password |`

Вот результат (не выполнился шаг где данные берутся из таблицы):
`1 scenario (1 undefined) 4 steps (1 skipped, 1 undefined, 2 passed) 0m15.521s`

Comment: Given-When-Then. Дано-Делаю-Происходит. У вас там явно When должен быть вместо Then. И, возможно, And. Вам надо скорее на описание Gherkin (языка Cucumber) смотреть, а не в Ruby :)

Comment: @D-side Given-When-Then не важны именно в таком порядке. Может быть и Given-Then-Then. Gherkin читает сценарий, а вот кукумбер пропускает шаги, т.к. ожидает в теле шага код.

Comment: When может и отсутствовать, да, просто Then должен описывать "ожидаемое происходящее", а не совершаемые вами действия. Ошибка может быть нетехнической и не влиять на результат, но она есть.

Comment: Суть в том, что в сценарии Then может быть множество: Given-When-Then-Then-...-n. На отработку это не влияет.

Comment: Может. Без вопросов. Просто в остальном выглядит правильно. На стороне Ruby никакая работа с массивами не требуется, каждая строчка таблицы будет подставлена в шаблон, и получится набор обыкновенных примеров с единичными значениями.

Comment: @D-side думаю все же код должен быть, т.к. как раз на шаги ввод пишет undefined. Получается отрабатывает первый шаг (passed)

Comment: `undefined` не очень похоже на массив. Я б даже сказал, очень **не** похоже.

Comment: @D-side т.к. кода в шаге нет, то cucumber пропускает его - я это так понимаю. А про массивы это мое предположение - тут же таблица. Вы сами запускали такой тест?

Comment: Могу запустить, если нужно, но смысла не вижу. Сам сценарий, с виду, проблем не содержит. Проблема если где-то и есть, то скорее в определениях шагов.

Comment: @D-side вот результат : `1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (1 skipped, 1 undefined, 2 passed)
0m15.521s` Видоизменил чуть его `Scenario Outline: As a valid user I can log into my app
    Given I have table Text 
    Then I enter text "text@mail" into field with id "login_email"  
    Then I enter text <Text> into field with id <id>
    Then I press the "ok" button
    Examples:
     | Text       | id             |
     | Welkom123# | login_password |`

Comment: 2 шага выполнилось, один не нашёлся, и шаг после него пропустился т. к. до него не получилось успешно дойти. Вероятно, `Then I press the <button> button` не попал под ту регулярку, что вы хотели (в определениях шагов). Или какой там у вас третий по счёту...

Comment: @D-side я забиваю первое поле данными из шага, далее хочу взять данные из таблицы, и кнопку ужу прописал по имени, и все равно нет результата.

Comment: Единичный пример лучше включить в вопрос, и я, кажется, вижу проблему. Кавычки.

Comment: @D-side черт возьми! Это действительно так! Отработал! Я потратил на эту проблему около 16 часов... Спасибо!

Comment: @D-side будуте отписывать ответ?

Comment: Лень, если честно. Можете сами, я не обижусь. :)

Comment: @D-side ок) еще раз спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выполнения `Scenario Outline` не нужно писать код для заполнения поле `< >` - Cucumber уже позаботился об этом! Чтобы сценарий корректно отработал нужно взять в кавычки значения из таблицы `Examples`. Вот так:

`Examples:
        | text         | id               | button |
        | "email_1"    | "login_email"    | "Ok"   |
        | "password_1" | "login_password" | "Ok"   |`

Comment: А ещё можно утащить кавычки в сам шаблон и не повторять их по сто раз :)